# Magento cronjob ignores crontab schedule configuration

Tags: php, magento, cron

I'm facing off the following problem:

every time I run/open the ***cron.php***-file from the Magento-Shop the Module I configured gets executed irrespective of its configuration on ***cron_expr***.

This is the crontab configuration in the ***config.xml*** file

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <cronjob>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 10 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>cronjob/observer::setStatus</model>
            </run>
        </cronjob>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

This is the Method that gets executed

```
public function setStatus() {
    Mage::Log("Hello World", null, "cronlog.log");
}
```

And this are my cronjob configuration in the Magento admin

- ***Generate Schedules Every:*** 5
- ***Schedule Ahead for:*** 20
- ***Missed if Not Run Within:*** 15
- ***History Cleanup Every:*** 10
- ***Success History Lifetime:*** 60
- ***Failure History Lifetime:*** 600
- ***Mark jobs as failed after:*** 120
- ***Heartbeat task schedule (cron syntax):*** */5 * * * *

Now everytime I open the Cron.php in browser this method gets executed and I don't know why.

Does someone know this problem and/or knows a Solution for it?